# Bhagadatta punishing Naraka and Mura

Tags: mahabharata

As I know, in Sabha Parva it is described that Bhagadatta punished the Naraka and Mura Yavanas. These are the same Naraka (son of Varaha and Bhumi) and Mura (the commander of Naraka)? If so, if Bhagadatta punished the two, why did Krishna kill them both and why Aditi's earrings, as well as the 16000 women, were still captive? Or were they different people?

Comment: *There are others also .... that wait upon Jarasandha. **He also that beareth on his head that gem which is known as the most wonderful on earth, that king of the Yavanas, who hath chastised Muru and Naraka, whose power is unlimited, and who ruleth the west like another Varuna, who is called Bhagadatta**, and who is the old friend of thy father, hath bowed his head before Jarasandha, by speech and specially by act. In his heart, however, tied as he is by affection to thee,...*.

Are you considering this statement from Sabha Parva?
http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02014.htm

Comment: Yes, since I am curious if they are the same or are different people

Comment: Please try to post corresponding Sanskrit sloka also, if possible, because the word *chastise* have some other meanings such as refusing, scolding etc., also.